# How to use typeahead with TNTSearch in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, typeahead.js, bloodhound

How can I point the index file generated from `php artisan tntsearch:import App\\User` to the Twitter Typeahead Bloodhound JavaScript file so that it can retrieve the search result from there?

The index file generated is called `user_index.index` in the Laravel storage directory. The Laravel User class uses `Searchable.`

In my typeahead-bloodhound.js file:

```
var suggestions = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace

    // Where & how to put the user_index.index file?
});

$('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'users',
        source: suggestions
    });
```

In my HTML:

```
<div id="bloodhound">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="search user">   
</div>
```

Now nothing happens (no suggestion) if I type some name in the search box.  I have no problem running the "the-basics" example shown in https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

I appreciate any help on this.  There doesn't seem to be a good example showing exactly how to use Laravel TNTSearch generated index file with typeahead.js.